Slow response of digital filter to signal amplitude change
I have a narrow-band rejection filter with the following parameters:

I noticed that if I feed a sine wave from a generator with a frequency of 500 Hz, the filter works fine, but if I change the amplitude of this sine wave, then at the moments of amplitude change the signal is passed. That is, if I change the amplitude, at the moment of change I see the signal, but after it fades away (suppressed by the filter.) As I understand it, this happens due to the slow response of the filter. Is it possible to somehow suppress the signal at a frequency of 500 Hz with a faster response? Initially, I digitize the signal at a frequency of 48 kHz, then I thin it out to a frequency of 2 kHz, having passed it through a 1 kHz low-pass filter (the band I need) before that. Then I detect the signal (I take it by the module) and take its envelope having passed it through a 6 Hz low-pass filter.
Hilmar suggested

track the interferer's exact frequency and phase with a PLL (phase locked loop), determine it's amplitude with least square error fit and than simply subtract it out

If I understood correctly, I tried to do it like this: I have an input signal from the ADC, the sampling frequency is 48 kHz. I pass it through a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 1 kHz, then there is a decimation by 24 times, I get a frequency of 2 kHz. The resulting signal is stored in the variable lp1000. Then I do this:
float reference_signal=0, freq=500, phase=0, phase_error=0, 
amplitude_estimate=0, error_signal=0;

reference_signal = sinf(M_TWOPI * freq / 2000 + phase); 
phase_error = lp1000 * reference_signal; 
phase += 0.01 * phase_error;
freq += 0.01 * phase_error; 
if (phase > M_TWOPI) phase -= M_TWOPI;

amplitude_estimate = (amplitude_estimate + lp1000 * reference_signal) / 2.0; 
error_signal = lp1000 - amplitude_estimate * reference_signal;

As a result, on the exhale (error_signal) I saw just the same 500Hz. Why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong?

please don't abuse tags! [tag:dsp-core] is not what you are doing.

To see where the problem is, you can simply look at the group delay in filter designer:

You can see that it peaks at over 800 samples in the 500 Hz area and that is indicative of the response time of the filter. Unfortunately that is expected: the narrower the filter is, the slower it will respond. Its a consequence of the Fourier Uncertainty Principle.
Filter design is often about trade-off, in this case it will be between the desired magnitude response and time domain distortion and delay/responsiveness. I'm guessing you'd be better off with a simple 2nd order notch with a Q of about 60 or thereabouts. That should give you a group delay in the 100 sample range but with a phase flip at 500 Hz.
If your goal is to remove a narrow band interferer and alternative would be the following method: track the interferer's exact frequency and phase with a PLL (phase locked loop), determine it's amplitude with least square error fit and than simply subtract it out. This can remove the noise without impacting the rest of the signal at all. The response time can simply be adjusted through the lowpass filter in the PLL and you can even make it adaptive if that's required.

Can you tell us more about the alternative method? I know for sure that my interference source will be in the range of 495-505 Hz (almost always it is exactly 500 Hz, but I took a reserve of +-5 Hz). But its amplitude can change. I tried to put a simple 4th order butterworth filter of 495-505 with a group delay of 100 cycles. It seems to me that it has become better, but with every change in amplitude I see a signal...

I tried the alternative method you suggested. If I understood correctly, I implemented it like this: reference_signal = sinf(M_TWOPI * freq / 2000 + phase); phase_error = res_adc * reference_signal; phase += 0.01 * phase_error; freq += 0.01 * phase_error; if (phase > M_TWOPI) phase -= M_TWOPI; amplitude_estimate = (amplitude_estimate + res_adc * reference_signal) / 2.0; error_signal = res_adc - amplitude_estimate * reference_signal; But it doesn't work.

@red15530: I can't read your code from the comments, so please edit you question and add it there. What debug did you do? What unit tests did you run and which passed and which failed?

Sorry, I added my code with explanations to my question.

The simple answer
You can change filter order to trade off transition band of frequency response vs duration of transient effects. A lower order filter will improve the behavior when amplitude changes but will degrade the frequency response shape.
The explanation
To add to Hilmar’s great answer let us first understand why you see what you describe?
You state that the rejection fails “at the moment the amplitude changes”. This shouldn’t come as a surprise since a 500Hz with a changing amplitude is in fact an amplitude modulated signal with a finite bandwidth.
Now, if you do a single change in amplitude, you don’t really have a modulated signal over time, and the question becomes how long is the “memory” of the filter?
For an IIR like you design, the formal answer is infinite memory, but practically, after some number samples we can declare the impact to be negligible, depending on your sensitivity. This “memory length”, correlates to group delay as well as to filter order.
A lower order filter will reduce the effective “memory length”, and thus will reduce the amount of time that the signal is viewed as an amplitude modulated signal due to a single change in amplitude. However this will make you bandstop filter smoother, which might have undesirable effects for you.
